# macos: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables while install R pachage

Tags: r, macos-sierra, configure

I was facing this problem while installing R package devtools. My R studio is in Anaconda, and it's the latest version. The code is this:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

And I got response as follows:

```
also installing the dependency ‘git2r’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/git2r_0.21.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1155512 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.13.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 486555 bytes (475 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 475 KB

* installing *source* package ‘git2r’ ...
** package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/mh/df2k68vs4g3714qyztvg2y980000gn/T/RtmppuLmjL/R.INSTALL8f6b17805a/git2r':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/Users/nora/anaconda3/lib/R/library/git2r’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘git2r’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Users/nora/anaconda3/lib/R/library/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/mh/df2k68vs4g3714qyztvg2y980000gn/T/Rtmpyjv9BV/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

To fix this problem, I've tried the following but nothing changed:

1. check Xcode and command line tools, and make surethe command line tools is the latest version.
2. update all the anaconda package.
3. update homebrew
4. update gcc
5. restart my laptop.

Now I've  installed this package by using this code in terminal:

```
conda install -c r r-devtools
```

when I type `install.packages("devtools")` in my R console, nothing seems wrong and I saw feedback as following:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.13.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 486555 bytes (475 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 475 KB

* installing *source* package ‘devtools’ ...
** package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (devtools)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/mh/df2k68vs4g3714qyztvg2y980000gn/T/Rtmpyjv9BV/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

But I'm not sure whether I still have C compiler problem. If so, I still want to fix that for future's convenience. And still, I don't know why I countered this problem in the first place.

Comment: See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60481297/8508004).